# Manga in which a bus or car crashes, leaving three survivors in a cursed forest or island

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror

I remember seeing this manga, I think on Tapas, but I'm not sure.

I don't remember too much of it, though I strongly remember this scene: a bus crashes/car crashes and the people fall into this river where there are only two survivors; two guys, one blond and one has black hair. They see a surviving blonde girl and get her to safety, making three survivors. (I think they landed at a cursed forest/island).

Then this big scene where the blond guy sleeps against a tree and the other two sleep against each other. Once the blond guy wakes up, he is basically devoid of body fat and that's because he has all these red worms in his back. So the girl and black-haired guy cut him open and use a torch to burn all the worms while they are still in the guy's back.

I remember it being very good but I can't recall the name does anyone know?

Comment: This may be Class 1-9, on Webtoons. Bus crash, deserted island. But there's significantly more than 3 survivors - at least at first, I'm sure they all die eventually. Moreover, while it's horror and the art style is suitably twisted, as far as I can tell there are no SciFi/Fantasy elements to it - it's not a cursed island, it's just off the coast of North Korea. Is this the story you were looking for?

Comment: I know the story you are referring to and no it's not. Thank you for trying though :)